# Are they any browsers without double-tap zoom feature?

Tags: browser, zooming

I am looking for a browser to use on an Android tablet or mobile device that either does not have a double-tap zoom feature or where the double-tap zoom feature can be disabled. There are  other uses for "double clicking" on the web, but is currently impossible when a "double tap" always zooms the page instead.

Comment: Is that a function of the browser or of the multi-touch aspects of the touch-screen?

Comment: Double click events on web sites really ?
What a bad idea !
Do you have examples ?

Answer (score 1):

I use [Dolphin Broswer HD](https://market.android.com/details?id=mobi.mgeek.TunnyBrowser). It doesn't zooms on double clicking. You can try this.

Comment: I use Dolphin Browser also and it zooms on double-click. Do you think it really could be a function of the device I'm using (rooted Nook tablet)?

Comment: What you are using is Dolphin Browser Mini. I am talking about Dolphin Browser HD. Both are different and the later one doesn't have double-click zoom functionality.

Comment: Actually I am using Dolphin Browser HD.

Comment: For me its working (not zooming on double click). Need to check this on other devices.

Comment: Dolphin Browser HD zooms on double tap... Double tap on big page which could be zoomed, not on mobile pages.

Answer (score 0):

Try [UC Browser](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.UCMobile.intl&hl=en) it has both zoom and without zoom display settings.