# Annoying "unzoom" when browsing text

Tags: zooming

The following happens in various applications such as more than one type of web browser and Adobe's PDF reader. I'm scrolling through text at a comfortable zoom level, and then suddenly, I touch the screen the wrong way, and it zooms way out.  How can we prevent this UI behavior?

Answer (score 0):

This feature is known as double-tap zoom. In the stock browser, it can't be disabled, but it can be adjusted in `Settings -> Accessibility -> Zoom on double-tap`. According to [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/16674/475) , Dolphin Browser HD supports disabling it.

Comment: I can't find this menu item on my device.  I'm looking to disable UN zoom, not zoom.  As far as I can tell, I'm not double tapping anything when this happens. I'm not aware of any kind of double tapping on the phone. Everything everywhere, like launching a program, works by single tap. An alternate action is indicated by a long press. Double tap is a desktop/mouse thing.

Comment: There is no such thing like "UN zoom". You either "zoom in" or you "zoom out". And double-tap is something very practicable on every touch sensitive device, if configured correctly (i.e. the time frame between the taps must be set up correctly: make it too short, and it never works -- make it too long, and it fires too often).

Comment: I experimented with this double tap and see that it does zoom in and out. But I do not double tap when it zooms out by accident. It seems to be something akin to switch bounce. I would ideally like to disable double tap entirely, or configure it so that it is more difficult to execute. I don't think that double tap to zoom in and out is a useful feature, because it zooms all the way in or out.

Comment: Sometimes it can happen if you're holding the phone and touching part of the screen without knowing it; you then drag (perhaps with a finger on the other hand); the combination is a zoom in or out.